# this.width within a class always returns the same value

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Within my AS3 class I am calling `this.width`, and the value it returns is always 1, even though this is impossible given the contents of the object.

Is this a standard behavior for AS3?

Simple version of class is posted below. It is attached to a MovieClip symbol that just contains a simple hexagon.

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Hexagon extends MovieClip
    {
        var startWidth:Number;
        var startHeight:Number;

        public function Hexagon() 
        {
            var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000);
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerFunction);
            myTimer.start();

            startWidth = this.width;
            startHeight = this.height;

            trace("startWidth:" + " " + startWidth);
            trace("startHeight:" + " " + startHeight);
        }

        function timerFunction (evt:TimerEvent):void
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is you're not using Silverlight.

Comment: What class do yours extends ?
Maybe you can post a simplified version of it, without it it's hard to tell what the problem may be.

Comment: Extends MovieClip. I've ammended my original question to include simplified code.

Comment: Hi cmal, your code above does not demonstrate the issue. Can you post more code, or show some images?

Comment: There isn't any more code. This is everything. I created a new MovieClip in Flash CS4, and have it linked as Hexagon so that it uses this class. When the SWF is compiled, it traces "1" and "1" for the width and height to the console, even though the Hexagon clip is more than 100 pixels tall. Given the code I've posted here, anybody should be able to easily duplicate the exact same conditions as mine.

Comment: I should also note that the Timer creation and associated function shown here are not doing anything, I just included them in this code because I intend to use them and wanted to make sure they weren't part of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I tested your code, both on the timeline and in the document class. I had no problems. Double check your export settings.

Comment: I tested too, works for me too...there is something else that messes it up. @Ben M cute :)) The problem is he isn't using C# when Silverlight developers piggy back ride Flash to export nice graphics to the Silverlight drawing api :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is standard, it's because you're asking for the width and height in the Constructor, at which point the property/accessor settings are not established.  Wait until the properties have been set officially, which is most reliably after `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`.  This is working for me:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class Movie extends MovieClip
    {
        public var startWidth:Number;
        public var startHeight:Number;

        public function Movie() 
        {
            var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000);
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerFunction);
            myTimer.start();

            startWidth = this.width;
            startHeight = this.height;

            trace("startWidth:" + " " + startWidth);
            trace("startHeight:" + " " + startHeight);
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        }

        public function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            startWidth = this.width;
            startHeight = this.height;

            trace("new startWidth:" + " " + startWidth);
            trace("new startHeight:" + " " + startHeight);
        }

        public function timerFunction(evt:TimerEvent):void
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helps,
Lance